# Used VMware Player Free, and now can't login to Ubuntu after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, login, vmware-player, xubuntu

Recently I installed VMware Player Free, in the form of the latest version, in my laptop running Xubuntu 14.04 Trusty. I then set up another linux OS to run as a virtual machine thereon, X'd out of it shortly thereafter, and went back to using Chrome for a bit. The computer seized up at some point, and I had to reboot.

Once I'd rebooted, I found that whenever I enter my login password successfully now, I just flash quickly to a black screen, and go right back to the login prompt again... and again... and again. It won't load.

The message I saw for a split second each time was: "Starting VMware AMQP Service: failed", "saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned", and "*restoring resolver state".

Please, if there's any other way to fix this than with a reinstall, then I will do it. My semesters notes and work and projects are all there, so I really need your help if you will. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your guest is locked.  Go to the folder that has the VMWARE Virtual machine files.  Rename the files that end in .lck to .bak for safe keeping.  Then try opening your virtual machine again.

Also, you may have to close the process that ends in .vmx.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ubuntu 14.04 stopped booting at the AMQP service failed message and won't continue to boot. Because I was testing video card drivers at the time, it turned out that after reinstalling my video drivers again the AMQP error was gone.

Regards
Moob